# Console interface navigation and connect it to the main class

Tags: java, console

I need to make the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 to work as they are required, but the thing is I don't know how. Here's the code:

```
        System.out.println("2) Select a Filter"); Kernel.java
        System.out.println("3) Additional Parameters Here...."); 
        System.out.println("4) Quit"); 
        System.out.println("\nSelect Option [1-4]>");
```

Thing is, I don't know how to do it so I thought about writing this on my code:

```
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 4;
```

After I have to connect it to my main class:

```
public class ImageProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runner.main();
        
    }
}
```

If you need any more detail, just ask, I will provide anything

Part 2
After setting up the console and the first and fourth function. I need to set up the 2 option which will lead me to choose a filter for my image

```
double[][] kernel = Kernel.SOBEL_HORIZONTAL;
        kernel = Kernel.SOBEL_VERTICAL;
        kernel = Kernel.VERTICAL_LINES;
        kernel = Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_1;
        kernel = Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_2;
        kernel = Kernel.LAPLACIAN;
        kernel = Kernel.SHARPEN;
        kernel = Kernel.BOX_BLUR;
        kernel = Kernel.DIAGONAL_45_LINES;
        kernel = Kernel.IDENTITY;
        kernel = Kernel.HORIZONTAL_LINES;


        //One can refer to them directly like this:
        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.SOBEL_VERTICAL.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.SOBEL_VERTICAL[row].length; col++){

            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.IDENTITY.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.IDENTITY[row].length; col++){

            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.HORIZONTAL_LINES.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.HORIZONTAL_LINES[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.VERTICAL_LINES.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.VERTICAL_LINES[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_1.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_1[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_2.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.EDGE_DETECTION_2[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.LAPLACIAN.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.LAPLACIAN[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.SHARPEN.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.SHARPEN[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.BOX_BLUR.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.BOX_BLUR[row].length; col++){

            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < Kernel.DIAGONAL_45_LINES.length; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < Kernel.DIAGONAL_45_LINES[row].length; col++){

            }
        }
```

This is what I have for the filters, will it server me?

Comment: Do you want to ask the user a input and act upon it, like if the user wants to implement filter then they would enter 2 and you need to compare it and call the filter action ?Is it right.

Comment: Understood, thank you. And for example if I want to implement several filters in one function, how would I do that?

Comment: You need to add more code details so that I can answer your query also you can store filters in key-value pairs and that you can get from Hashmap if your filters are unique.

Comment: Code ready, this is what I currently have

Comment: Your code must be failing when you do this ``Kernel.SOBEL_HORIZONTAL;``

Comment: Currently I have no errors related to SOBEL_HORIZONTAL, but is there I can do to avoid getting future errors?

Comment: Okay can you tell me what is the value of Kernel.SOBEL_HORIZONTAL and others

Comment: Well uh, they don't really have a value right now. I am not even sure if the code section with the kernels is correct